# Is it possible to Clear (recover memory from) a specific index to a variable, while leaving other indices to the same variable untouched?

Tags: warning-messages, variable-definitions, memory

Consider the following method commonly used to clear a typical variable:

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
(* {1, 2, 3} *)

ByteCount[data]
(* 112 *)

Clear[data]

ByteCount[data]
(* 0 *)
```

No problem.  Now, if I store the same information in an indexed variable, problems arise.

```
mytest[data] = {1, 2, 3}
(* {1, 2, 3} *)

ByteCount[mytest[data]]
(* 112 *)

Clear[mytest[data]]

During evaluation of Clear::ssym: mytest[data] is not a symbol or a string.

ByteCount[mytest[data]]
(* 112 *)
```

Is there a way to clear the values of indexed values so they don't consume memory?

My primary application requires large volumes of data to be stored in indexed variables, and at appropriate times, I would like to be able to "erase" that data from memory as my datasets are really big (multiple GBs per file).

---

Following initial comments, I realized I needed to re-word my initial question. (which I've done.)  Taking advice from the comments, it seems Unset may be the way to go here.

Notice:

```
mytest[data] = {1, 2, 3}
(* {1, 2, 3} *)

mytest[data2] = {4, 5, 6, 7}
(* {4, 5, 6, 7} *)

ByteCount[mytest[data]]
(* 112 *)

ByteCount[mytest[data2]]
(* 136 *)

mytest[data] =.

ByteCount[mytest[data]]
(* 48 *)

mytest[data]
(* mytest[data] *)

mytest[data2]
(* {4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

As an add on, why is there a small amount of memory still attached to mytest[data] after performing the Unset operation?

Comment: `ClearAll[mytest]`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Unset`: `mytest[data] =.`

Comment: Beware that the values might have also been bound to `Out` so you might need to clear that too if you really need the memory back.

Comment: @kglr After reading your response, I realized my initial question was not defined as specifically as it should have.  I need to clear memory from a specific index while leaving data associated with other indices untouched.  I've modified my question and thank you for responding.

Comment: @ToddAllen, so wait, what is wronog with `Unset`?

Comment: @Michael E2  Thank you. Unset does seem to allow me to selectively clear memory associated with specific indices, while leaving others alone.  Still the ByteCount does not go to zero, any thoughts why not?  (see edit example above)

Comment: I tried to explain it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Byte count is 64, for entry in indexed variable. Even if there is no data

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As mentioned in comment, use `=.` to clear specific index

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Too long for a comment:

`ByteCount[mytest[data]]` measures the memory required for the expression `mytest[data]`.  The [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) of a `Symbol` is always zero; see the docs for `ByteCount`:

> Symbols are effectively always shared, so they give 0 byte count:

In other words (I think), it does not count the memory required to store the symbol in the symbol/hash table.

The OP's first `ByteCount[data]` computes `ByteCount[{1, 2, 3}]` because `data` evaluates to the expression `{1, 2, 3}` before `ByteCount` is called.  Consider

```
Trace[ByteCount@data]
(*  {{data, {1, 2, 3}},
     ByteCount[{1,2,3}],
     112}  *)
```

Also consider the difference between the evaluated and unevaluated `data`:

```
data = {1, 2, 3}; 
ByteCount /@ {data, Unevaluated@data}
(*  {112, 0}  *)
```

@Nasser's example `ByteCount[a[1]]` gives 64 bytes and the OP's `ByteCount[mytest[data]]` gives 48 bytes (after `data` is cleared).  Here is an accounting of it:

```
Clear[a, b];
ByteCount@ 1
ByteCount@ a[b]
ByteCount@ a[1]
(*
  16  - storage of one integer
  48  - storage of the head--argument tree expression
  64  - total
*)
```

One can carry this accounting game further. For instance, `ByteCount@ 2[1]`
gives `80`.  However, beware that according to the docs,

> `ByteCount` will...often give an overestimate of the amount of memory...needed....

Back to the principal question, which has already been answered, how to free up memory when a value is no longer needed:

- [`Unset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html) will remove a single value (definition).
- [`Clear`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) will remove all values (definitions) but not attributes, options, defaults or messages.
- [`ClearAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html) will remove all values, attributes, options, defaults and messages.
- [`Remove`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Remove.html) removes the symbol (thereby all things associated with it) from the symbol table.

See the docs for more information.  As has been noted in the comments and @Nasser's answer, `Unset` is the desired solution in the OP's case.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. It is detailed responses like this that really start to peel back the "petals of ignorance."  Much obliged.